# ExpressionEngine Override Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, overriding, expressionengine

We want to make some changes to the Content_edit class for ExpressionEngine (system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/content_edit.php)

We don't want to make these change directly to this file, so that we don't have trouble upgrading in the future.

Is there a way we can take a copy of this file, add our functionality, and somehow use this new file to override the ExpressionEngine version? If so does anyone have any examples?

Comment: You will need to make a backup copy content_edit.php and change original file , when you need to upgrade just revert it back. If you make new file/class than you need to change ExpressionEngine to use your new class, which is more trouble especially if  Content_edit class is used in some other classes. There may be another soulutions ie if you can code ExpressionEngine to use your new class. You did not mention what is this framework name so we can look deeper.

Comment: From the developer documentation: "Within ExpressionEngine are what is known as ‘hooks’; little snippets of code in over 100 strategic places that allow the calling of third-party scripts that can rewrite and modify the inner workings of the program. Extensions can do things like modify an entire Control Panel page, add/remove functionality, and modify the appearance of certain page elements."   Sounds like the best approach would be to write an 'extension' based on a 'hook', if there is one present for your purposes. https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html